# Is there a non-empty open set in $\mathbb{R}^3$ whose elements satisfy the following equality?

Tags: analysis

Is there a non-empty open set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that the equality $x+2xz^2=y+2x^2y$ holds for all $(x,y,z)\in S$ ? If not, how to see non-existence of such a non-empty open set? Could someone give a clue?

Comment: Sorry, I should be more explicit!

Comment: I mean, I asked for a non-empty open subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Suppose $a,b\in\mathbb R$ and $b\gt0$. Is there a non-empty open set $S$ in $\mathbb R$ such that the equality $a=by$ holds for all $y\in S$?

Comment: Of course, there is no such an open set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Then that answers your question, doesn't it? Choose a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)\in S$. Then $T=\{y:(x_0,y,z_0)\in S\}$ is a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb R$. Let $a=x_0+2x_0z_0^2$ and $b=1+2x_0^2\gt0$; then $a=by$ holds for all $y\in T$. I thought that was a pretty good hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that there is a non- empty open set $S$ with the above properties. Let $(x_0,y_0,z_0) \in S$. Since $S$ is open, there is $t>0$ sich that $(x_0,y_0+t,z_0) \in S$.

Therefore $x_0+2x_0z_0^2=y_0+t+2x_0^2(y_0+t)$. Since $x_0+2x_0z_0^2=y_0+2x_0^2y_0$, this gives $t+2x_0^2t=0$. This is a contradiction, since $t+2x_0^2t \ge t>0.$